# Find Metrics using Stagemonitor

Tags: java, performance, stagemonitor

I am trying to using stagemonitor for get metrics for different methods. I used sample PetClinic application locally for get a idea. I want to get metrics only what i need , not all of them is any possible to do that.
I change some code for my testing purpose

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testing(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Owner owner = new Owner();
    model.put("owner", owner);
    return VIEWS_OWNER_CREATE_OR_UPDATE_FORM;
}
```

when i click test button in html it will go to this method and i can get the metrics form stagemonitor.If i not need to see this method metrics ,how to stop showing that in stagemonitor

@Felix

I trying to use browser-widget in example and i change code for testing. 
 [image]

This output I'm getting i don't want to see details about Testing.I only want to see some method i need, even other methods used i don't want to see about them. is it possible  ??

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Which metrics do you want to stop showing. And why? Try to describe what the underlying problem is. Do you want to disable the in-browser-widget? Do you want certain things in the in-browser-widget to to be displayed? Or are you referring to the Kibana dashboards?

Comment: I edit question to get a idea.

Comment: You can use the search bar to filter the requests. Would that work for you?

Comment: Yes that can be done.But i like if unwanted method details not showing at all. Thanks for helps.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why would you want that?

Comment: I think to get method details only that i need to see. Is that a way to see details of standalone-test application in browser-widget ?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions.

You can have a button 'hide', that will hide the metrics using some javascript code.

Or in the same button you do the following:

```
private boolean metricsOn = false;

@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testing(Map<String, Object> model) {

    if(!metricsOn){
metrics = true;

    Owner owner = new Owner();
    model.put("owner", owner);
    return VIEWS_OWNER_CREATE_OR_UPDATE_FORM;
} else{
//return without the given metrics?
metrics = false;
 return VIEWS_OWNER_CREATE_OR_UPDATE_FORM;
}
```